# How can I make PHP's fgetcsv() to recognize the Classic Mac (CR) new line character?

Tags: php, newline, fgetcsv

I use this code to get the number of columns from a CSV file:

```
$this->dummy_file_handler = fopen($this->config['file'],'r');
if ($dataset =fgetcsv($this->dummy_file_handler))
{
    $this->number_of_columns = count($dataset);
}
```

It works fine **unless** the file is exported with Excel for Mac 2011 since the new line character is then  **Classic Mac (CR)** which `fgetcsv` doesn't recognize.

[image]

If I **manually** change the newline from Classic Mac (CR) to Unix (LR), then it works, but I need this to be automated.

**How can I make `fgetcsv` recognize the Classic Mac (CR) new line character?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> Note: If PHP is not properly
>   recognizing the line endings when
>   reading files either on or created by
>   a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time
>   configuration option may help resolve
>   the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If Saul's answer doesn't work, I'd write a simple script to read in the file all at once and str_replace all \r with \n, dumping the results into a new file, then fgetcsv'ing that new file.

I find it amusing that these terms come from the days of using typewriters:
\n = Line Feed(LF) - advances the paper one line.
\r = Carriage Return (CR) - returns the carriage to the left side of the typewriter.